# I can't send email to Outlook

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-2

Hi everyone i have already tried email sending using php code igniter.
but it send to only gmail and yahoo mail. it doesn't send to any other server like live.com , Outlook etc. please help me.

```
$this->load->helper('email');
$this->load->library('email'); // load the library
$config = Array(
                         'protocol' => 'smtp',
                         'smtp_host' => 'mail.xxxxxx.com',
                         'smtp_port' => 25,
                         'smtp_user' => 'info@xxxxxx.com', // change it to yours
                         'smtp_pass' => '', // change it to yours
                         'mailtype' => 'html',
                         'charset' => 'utf-8',
                         'wordwrap' => TRUE,
                         'crlf' => '\r\n',
                        'newline' => '\r\n'
                        );  
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

Comment: Check spam folder. If it can send out emails to Gmail, it can be sent to other servers as well (unless a firewall intentionally blocked those servers).

Comment: yes i checked but not recieved

Comment: Check your mail server, not your mail client. In most cases, server will filter spam mails away (by software like SpamAssassin, etc)

Comment: have you tried using native php instead of codeigniter i have encounter this issues.

Comment: yes . it doen't send